# Unknown column in 'field list' error MySQL in INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement when using constants

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an issue with my SQL query.

I am trying to transfer data between two tables using PHP and I can't wrap my head around how to fix this.

My code looks like this:

```
$newValue = "test";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table2` (`value1`, `value2`, `value3`, ..., `valueX`) SELECT `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, ..., `$newValue` FROM `table1`")
```

valueX in the INSERT INTO is meant to be the table that doesn't exist in table1.

What I'm having issues with is that if the $newValue is a number, for instance 2, the query works as intended. Allthough if I instead use a string, like in the example above, the query fails and I get the Unknown field error.

Could this have to do with that it tries to find a column with the *$newValue* name since it's a string and it doesn't do this if it's an integer? If so, is there a way to make it so I can add this static value in this query without it thinking that it's another column?

EDIT: My problem was fixed by replacing ` with ' at SELECT $newValue.

Comment: don't use backticks `\``, use quotes `'` -> `'$newValue'` when your value is a string.

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot when to use what, but this solved my issue! :)